# Print once after for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

```
for line in infileStudents:
    line = line.rstrip()
    parts = line.split(':')
    studentID = int(parts[0])
    studentName = parts[1]
    if studentID == ID:
       break
    else:
       print("No record")
```

I am trying to search for an ID number in a file and print a message if the ID doesn't exist in the file.

The above code reads each line and prints a message for each line.

How do I print only one message after I read all the IDs in the file?

Comment: Unindent the `else:` line and the one below it.

Comment: > "How do I print only one message after I read all the IDs in the file?" — accumulate the data which you need to print, and print it outside of the loop, later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code.

```
idFound =  False         # variable declared as a flag with default False
for line in infileStudents:
    line = line.rstrip()
    parts = line.split(':')
    studentID = int(parts[0])
    studentName = parts[1]
    if studentID == ID:
       idFound = True    # if Id found then changing flag variable to true to handle further excution of the code
       break

if idFound:   # handling here
   print("Id found")
else:
   print ("No record")
```

Comment: You have the exact same error, plus your code is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: OP wants to check for a particular `ID` in the file and your code checks if a file contains something or not... :-)

Comment: @MayurAgarwal There is no need to iterate on file's lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
if line not in infileStudents.read():
    print ("No record")
```

Try this. There is no need to search through every line when you can use `in` and check if it is `in` the entire file as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if ID does exist in file's content without iterating on file's lines like this:

```
if str(ID) in infileStudents.read():
    print("Id found")
else:
    print("No record")
```

Iterating in file's lines is useless rather than redundant.